# Android login app

Tags: android

I am developing an Android app. It has a login page in which I have to do session management for users and give each time `sessionid` for each time.

Comment: i have not started yet but i am thinking how to do it bcoz after that i also include chat for that users who registered and login.so i am preplanning how to doit and manage session.if you have already done some this kind of stuff pls guide me.thanks for response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know may be you want to implement this application as internet based:

See here is a basic tutorial on this:

[Simple Login Application in Android](http://androidsamples.blogspot.com/2009/06/how-to-use-http-connection-saxparser.html)

And  if you want to develop it standalone. Then you can either use [Database](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/package-summary.html) or [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to manage sessions by storing users data.